# firefox, how to get the content of location bar? (more words to pass censorship?)

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want get what I put in the address bar, such as "hello world", not:

```
var url = tabs.activeTab.url  // I don't want this
```

before I press enter in the address bar. Is it possible to do it in an addon?

Comment: I'm going to sleep so ill cheap out on a solution: This is non-sdk way -> Yes see this addon here: https://github.com/Noitidart/ntHotkey https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nthotkey/?src=search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define this function in your add-on:

```
function getURLBarText() {
  var { getMostRecentWindow } = require("sdk/window/utils");
  var urlBar = getMostRecentWindow().document.getElementById('urlbar');
  return urlBar.value;
}
```

Then calling `getURLBarText()` will return whatever is in your active window's url bar.